# optimize a select query which took 1 minute to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very short select query, but it took 1 minute to execute, how to optimize it?

```
SELECT dsss.[distID],
       dsss.[distname],
       (select count(applicationnumb) from tbl_applicant_case with(nolock) where tbl_applicant_case.[CourtDistId]=dsss.[distID] and tbl_applicant_case.case_numb is not null and [category]=N'अ-27') as ttlcaseentrered,
       (select count(applicationnumb) from tbl_applicant_case  with(nolock) where tbl_applicant_case.[CourtDistId]=dsss.[distID] and tbl_applicant_case.FinalOrder is not null and [category]=N'अ-27') as ttlcasedispopsed
FROM [tbl_district] as dsss
group by dsss.[distID], dsss.[distname]
order by ttlcaseentrered desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can simplify your query to this single `left join` instead of two subqueries (because a `null` value is not `count()`ed):

```
select 
    dsss.[distID]
  , dsss.[distname]
  , ttlcaseentrered  = count(ac.case_numb)
  , ttlcasedispopsed = count(ac.FinalOrder)
from [tbl_district] as dsss
  left join tbl_applicant_case as ac with(nolock) 
    on ac.[CourtDistId]=dsss.[distID] 
   and ac.[category]=N'अ-27'
group by dsss.[distID], dsss.[distname]
```

And the `count()` could be supported with an index like this:

```
create nonclustered index ix_tbl_applicant_case_CourtDistId_Category_cover 
  on tbl_applicant_case(CourtDistId, Category)
    include (CaseNumb, FinalOrder);
```

---

If `applicaitonnumb` is nullable, to count when both are not null you can use conditional aggregation like so:

```
select 
    dsss.[distID]
  , dsss.[distname]
  , ttlcaseentrered  = sum(case when ac.applicationnumb is not null and ac.case_numb is not null then 1 else 0 end)
  , ttlcasedispopsed = sum(case when ac.applicationnumb is not null and ac.FinalOrder is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from [tbl_district] as dsss
  left join tbl_applicant_case as ac with(nolock) 
    on ac.[CourtDistId]=dsss.[distID] 
   and ac.[category]=N'अ-27'
group by dsss.[distID], dsss.[distname]
```

And the index would also need to include `applicationnumb`:

```
create nonclustered index ix_tbl_applicant_case_CourtDistId_Category_cover 
  on tbl_applicant_case(CourtDistId, Category)
    include (CaseNumb, FinalOrder, applicationnumb);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select dsss.[distID],
       dsss.[distname],
       (select count(applicationnumb)
        from tbl_applicant_case ac
        where ac.[CourtDistId] = dsss.[distID] and
              ac.case_numb is not null and
              ac.[category] = N'अ-27'
      ) as ttlcaseentrered,
      (select count(applicationnumb) 
       from tbl_applicant_case ac
       where ac.[CourtDistId] = dsss.[distID] and
             ac.FinalOrder is not null and
             ac.[category]=N'अ-27'
      ) as ttlcasedispopsed
from [tbl_district] dsss
group by dsss.[distID], dsss.[distname]
order by ttlcaseentrered desc;
```

First, for the subqueries, you want an index on `tbl_applicant_case(CourtDistId, category)`.  This index could also include:  `FinalOrder`, `case_numb`, and `applicationnumb`.

Second, I don't see why `GROUP BY` is needed in the outer query.  I would suggest removing it, unless you really know that you need to remove duplicates.

Comment: as per your answer  i removed group by but it still took 45 sec

Comment: @ankitsoni . . . You need to add the indexes.